# SQL statement to update and set

Tags: sql

I would like to update a register in a database using a SQL Query

```
UPDATE bin SET binname = 'jejej' AND capacity = '8' WHERE binname = 'test' AND binid = '1'
```

I would like to update field `binname` and `capacity` to those values in case there is a `binname = test` and `binid = 1`

However, the register which exists in the base changes to binname = 0 and capacity do not change.

How can I create a good SQL statement for that? BINID is a integer, binname = text, capacity = real.

Thanks and Kind regards

Comment: What is a "register"?  That is not a database term.  I also removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 UPDATE bin SET binname = 'jejej',capacity = '8' WHERE binname = 'test' AND binid = '1'
```

Comment: Thanks :D Problem was the comma :)

Answer (score 3):

This code is syntactically incorrect in most databases:

```
UPDATE bin
    SET binname = 'jejej' AND capacity = '8'
    WHERE binname = 'test' AND binid = '1';
```

It would be interpreted as:

```
UPDATE bin
    SET binname = ('jejej' AND capacity = '8')
    WHERE binname = 'test' AND binid = '1';
```

That is `binname` would be set to the result of a boolean expression.  If your database supports boolean expressions, then `binname` is set to true or false (which get converted to `1` and `0`).  However, it would more commonly be an error.

The correct syntax for updating multiple columns uses a comma:

```
UPDATE bin
    SET binname = 'jejej',
        capacity = '8'
    WHERE binname = 'test' AND binid = '1';
```

Note:  If `capacity` and `binid` are *numbers*, then the associated literal values should be *numbers* and not strings:

```
UPDATE bin
    SET binname = 'jejej',
        capacity = 8
    WHERE binname = 'test' AND binid = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your explanation. Crystal clear to me :D